# Java String AES Encryption/Decryption not working

Tags: java, string, encryption, aes

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt a string in java using AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding. It encrypts/decrypts without any compilation errors but the string after decryption is just random characters. this is my code:

Encryption:

```
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(key.toCharArray(), "salt".getBytes(), 65536, 256);
SecretKey secret =new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded(),"AES");

byte[] iv = new byte[16];
new SecureRandom().nextBytes(iv);
IvParameterSpec ivp = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret, ivp);

byte[] encryptedText = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes("UTF-8));
return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedText);
```

Decryption:

```
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(key.toCharArray(), "salt".getBytes(), 65536, 256);
SecretKey secret =new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded(),"AES");

byte[] iv = new byte[16];
new SecureRandom().nextBytes(iv);
IvParameterSpec ivp = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, ivp);

byte[] decryptedtext = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(input));
return new String(decryptedtext, "UTF-8");
```

The given text is the same every time but the result changes and is filled with random characters.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to save the encryption IV and use the same one for decryption. Typically this is done by prepending it to the ciphertext. Note that using a fixed salt is effectively no better than having no salt at all.

Comment: You can find a complete example for AES CBC with PBKDF2 encryption here (disclaimer I'm the author) https://github.com/java-crypto/cross_platform_crypto/blob/main/AesCbc256Pbkdf2StringEncryption/AesCbc256Pbkdf2StringEncryption_Full.java